# Wordpress grab integer patterns and store into custom fields

Tags: wordpress

Im wonderig if is possible to auto grab integer patterns in post title and store into custom fields.

eg. post title is
home length is 300-500
kitchen room is 150.50-300

eg. data to grab into custom field for above posts is:
300 and 500,
150.5 and 300

im thinking along this process. if string match the integer pattern, add post meta

Answer (score 0):

You could hook into the `post_save` action in Wordpress that runs whenever a post is created or updated. then run a regular expression on the title and save any number matches into the post meta like so...

```
/**
 * On post save this function runs a regular expression to find
 * any decimal numbers in the title and save them as post meta
 * in a title_numbers field
 *
 * @param  {integer} $post_id the post_id gets passed from the post_save action
 * @return {boolean}          returns false if no numbers are found in the title
 */
function my_project_store_title_integers( $post_id ) 
{

    $post_title = get_the_title( $post_id );

    if ( preg_match_all( '/([0-9.]+)/', $post_title, $numbers ) )
    {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'title_numbers', $numbers[0] );
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'my_project_store_title_integers' );
```

put this in your `functions.php`. This function will be called automatically on post save but you could call it manually and pass it any post id eg...

```
my_project_store_title_integers( 22 );
```

This will save any numbers in the post title to an array in a meta field called 'title_numbers' so for example if the post title of post 22 is...

'post title is home length is 300-500 kitchen room is 150.50-300'

you could get the meta like so...

```
$meta = get_post_meta( 22, 'title_numbers', true );
print_r( $meta );

//output
Array
(
    [0] => 300
    [1] => 500
    [2] => 150.50
    [3] => 300
)
```

**UPDATE:** to test to see if the data is being stored try pasting in the following code into your `single.php` template...

```
<?php
$title_numbers = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'title_numbers', true );
if( $title_numbers ) {
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r( $title_numbers );
    echo '</pre>';
}
?>
```

If the metadata was saved correctly this code will output the metadata. try that.

Hope that helps

Dan

Comment: thanks Dan for your reply. :) Ive inserted the code into my function file but the custom field title_numbers is not created after post save.

Comment: How are you testing wether the post meta exists or not?

Comment: Hi Dan, by viewing through the screen options and custom fields

Comment: I have added a method you can use to test if the data is being stored.